# How can i solve the error Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, class

I've created a class of type `Posts` which has three fields of type string and I'm trying to access it from an Angular component class to set the three fields to their default values but I get the following error...

```
Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  
Property 'post1' must be of type 'Posts', but here has type 'any'
```

***Code of my `Posts` class***

```js
export class Posts{
    Key:string;
    Email:string;
    Password:string;
}
```

***Code of how I'm trying to set the values in my Angular component class***

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'proyecto-nro2';

  post1 = new Posts();
//Said the error above in every post1.
  post1.Key = 'NONE';
  post1.Email = 'NONE';
  post1.Password = '2';
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question, it's confusing

Comment: @Aravind I write it again, let me know if is still confusing, even i dont know how to explaine it very well

Comment: I still didn't understand

Comment: The problem is when i create a variable in another class and try to access to the attributes of his class doesn't let me and said the error above @Aravind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either ...

**1)** Add a constructor to the `Posts` class to assign values when creating the object with `new`. Using the `public` accessor in the constructor will automatically declare the parameters as publicly accessible properties.

```js
export class Posts {
  constructor(
    public key: string,
    public email: string,
    public password: string,
  ) { } 
}

export class AppComponent {
  // order of the parameters matters here
  // as it matches the order in the class constructor
  post1 = new Post('NONE', 'NONE', '2');
}
```

**2)** In the `AppComponent` you can simply assign the type `Posts` to your property and assign value without using `new`.

```js
export class Posts {
  key: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export class AppComponent {
  // order of the properties doesn't matter here
  // as long as the properties exist and match the type
  post1: Posts = {
    key: 'NONE',
    email: 'NONE',
    password: '2',
  };
}
```

If the value of the object have to be assign dynamically, this has to be done inside functions.

```js
export class Posts {
  key: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  post1 = new Posts();

  ngOnInit() {
    post1.key = 'NONE';
    post1.email = 'NONE';
    post1.password = '2';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a class, then look at 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html
and you could write your code similar to the following.

```
    export class Posts{
    key:string;
    email:string;
    password:string;
    constructor(key:string, email:string, password:string){
        this.key = key;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and in your component class

```
    post1: Posts = new Posts('NONE', 'NONE', '2');
```

Comment: I have also Same problem.I can't assign a export class property to another class.Why it shows Duplicate identifier in typescript.Please help.  :@rickz

Comment: You should  ask a new question. Post your code  and error message.